# JavaFX NullPointerException on Startup

Tags: linux, javafx

I'm trying to run a very simple JavaFX program using the Oracle JVM (1.7u13) on Linux (I have the correct version of GTK) running from Eclipse or the command line. As it starts it throws an exception moaning about fonts.  Font.getDefault() can also cause the same NPE.  I can list the available fonts using Font.getFontNames() and I can see 17 including 'System Regular' which I thought was the default.

Any ideas much appreciated!

The stack trace....

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:403)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.access$000(LauncherImpl.java:47)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$1.run(LauncherImpl.java:115)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.sun.t2k.LogicalFont.(LogicalFont.java:172)
        at com.sun.t2k.LogicalFont.getLogicalFont(LogicalFont.java:104)
        at com.sun.t2k.LogicalFont.getLogicalFont(LogicalFont.java:144)
        at com.sun.t2k.T2KFontFactory.createFont(T2KFontFactory.java:356)
        at com.sun.prism.j2d.J2DFontFactory.createFont(J2DFontFactory.java:38)
        at com.sun.javafx.font.PrismFontLoader.loadFont(PrismFontLoader.java:399)
        at javafx.scene.text.Font.(Font.java:282)
        at javafx.scene.text.Font.getDefault(Font.java:85)
        at com.me.FXProblem.start(FXProblem.java:23)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$5.run(LauncherImpl.java:319)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$5.run(PlatformImpl.java:215)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$4$1.run(PlatformImpl.java:179)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$4$1.run(PlatformImpl.java:176)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$4.run(PlatformImpl.java:176)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:76)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication$3$1.run(GtkApplication.java:82)
        ... 1 more
```

### Update

Sample code to get the error.  I'm assuming that the route cause of the Font.getDefault() is what is causing a couple of very simple UI nodes to not display.

```
    package com.me;

    import javafx.application.Application;
    import javafx.scene.text.Font;
    import javafx.stage.Stage;

    /**
     * Problem class to show the stack trace from Font.getDefault()
     */
    public class FXProblem extends Application
    {
        /**
         * {@inheritDoc}
         */
        @Override
        public void start(final Stage stage) throws Exception
        {
            Font.getDefault();
        }

        /**
         * Main.
         */
        public static void main(final String[] args)
        {
            launch();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please update question with the the code that fails and at least some of the context.

Comment: I ran your sample code on Java7u11 OS X 10.8 (2012 Macbook Air) and did not receive a `NullPointerException`, so I your error is environment specific.  Font used on my machine was `Font[name=System Regular, family=System, style=Regular, size=13.0]`.  Also, that stack trace appears unrelated to your sample code as it seems to be an error generated when the JavaFX tries to construct a warning message for a full screen overlay.

Comment: @jewelsea updated the stack trace but the route cause is the same, a NPE from LogicalFont line 172. I'm not surprised that the error is environment specific as, like you, I can run this successfully on a different OS. So, any ideas what might be wrong with the environment? There is some interaction between the OS and JavaFx which is wrong somewhere. Unfortunately I have no choice over the OS so need to get this going somehow :-/

Comment: Try the [Java 8 Preview](http://jdk8.java.net/download.html) and see if it is fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a known (currently open) issue with JavaFX 2.2:

[RT-28405 NPE when trying to load default font on Slackware linux](http://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-28405)

A login required to use the above bug tracker link, but anybody can sign up.

---

Reproducing (just copy and past) some of the comments from the issue here so casual users don't need to sign up to the bug tracker just to get access to them:

*User Submitted Workaround*

> I've managed to work around the issue by simply adding a TTF directory to /usr/share/fonts and adding at least on .ttf file to that directory. (/usr/share/fonts/TTF/somefont.ttf) Previously the only other directory in /usr/share/fonts was Type1. (/usr/share/fonts/Type1)

*Developer Provided Background Information*

> Since adding a TTF font to /usr/share/fonts works, then it seems like we are successfully
> using /usr/libfontconfig to locate the installed fonts, but apparently there were none to our liking. i.e. FX does not support Type 1 fonts (a policy decision), only TrueType and OpenType/CFF fonts. Are you running with OpenJDK or Oracle JDK? I'd bet an OpenJDK that wsa bundled with slackware OpenJDK has no fonts of its own, whereas OracleJDK has some of its own TrueType fonts so would not hit this problem. The bottom line here seems to be that you should install a decent set of TrueType fonts.
> I think the only thing we can do on our end is improve the diagonostic when this happens.

*User Provided Environment Information*

> I was using Oracle's JDK, so I was surprised to hit this. ( 7u10 ) But I agree with your assessment, installing new fonts to resolve this problem was no big deal, it was just difficult to figure out that that was the problem. (Since we did have other fonts installed) If you could detect this problem and provide better feedback, that would be acceptable from my point of view. Thanks!

Comment: Really helpful. Thanks for sharing this info. Not much help is available on internet regarding this.